# pgfSweave() results in texi2dvi error "Missing \endcsname inserted"

Tags: r, sweave

When running pgfSweave using a file with the following sample code:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\begin{document} 
In this example we embed parts of the examples from the
\texttt{kruskal.test} help page into a \LaTeX{} document :
<<>>=
data(airquality)
kruskal.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality)
@
\end{document}
```

and this command:

```
pgfSweave("sweave.Snw")
```

the following error occurs:

```
...(latex header)....
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")))
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
...(latex crashing out)...
```

This file works fine with this command:

```
Sweave("sweave.Snw")
```

and then "latex sweave.tex" at the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/227981.html):

> On Thu, Feb 11, 2010 at 6:36 PM, Yihui Xie  wrote:
>   If I understand pgfSweave correctly, a line like this
>
> `\usepackage{C:/PROGRA~1/R/some.version/share/texmf/Sweave}`
>
> will be added to the preamble of your LaTeX document if you didn't
>   explicitly add `\usepackage{Sweave}` by yourself.
>
> That will cause the error like
>
> Missing  `\endcsname` inserted

When I add `\usepackage{Sweave}` to the above file it works fine.

Comment: This issue just bites users again and again. It is one tiny reason motivating the `knitr` package: if you like `pgfSweave`, you probably can experiment with `library(knitr); knit('your_input.Rnw')` too.